# Rails form_for html being set to display: none

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a standard rails form_for tag for creating and editing a new hotel. This renders just fine when visited via the edit_hotels_path, however when visting the new_hotels_path the html form tag is being set to `display: none;` causing the form to not show only in the "new" view.

I have restarted the server, emptied the cache, made sure they are using the same CSS but it still renders with display set to none. 
Here are the styles as seen using developer tools

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/hotels" class="new_hotel" id="new_hotel" method="post" style="display: none; "><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="pDlR3gV2tm+Z7xRFdC0uclNY13FlzxUSOjOrHs2ttO0="></div>

element.style {
display: none;
}
```

below is the html source being rendered, which doesn't include display: none;

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/hotels" class="new_hotel" id="new_hotel" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="pDlR3gV2tm+Z7xRFdC0uclNY13FlzxUSOjOrHs2ttO0=" /></div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    <input id="hotel_name" name="hotel[name]" placeholder="Name..." size="30" type="text" /><br>
        <select id="hotel_year" name="hotel[year]"><option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option></select><br>
        <select id="hotel_month" name="hotel[month]"><option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option></select><br>

    <textarea cols="40" id="hotel_body" name="hotel[body]" placeholder="Hotel info up to 1000 words..." rows="20">
</textarea><br>
    <input id="hotel_meta_tags" name="hotel[meta_tags]" placeholder="Enter meta tags for image, as a comma separated list..." size="30" type="text" /><br>
<legend>Winner</legend>
        <input name="hotel[winner]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="hotel_winner" name="hotel[winner]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <br/>

    </div>
<div class="form-actions">
    <input class="btn-large btn-success" name="commit" type="submit" value="create" />
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

below is the code, would appreciated any help.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @hotel do |f| %>
<% if @hotel.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@hotel.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @hotel.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>


    <%= render partial: "shared/code_sheet" %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name..." %><br>
        <%= f.select :year, [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015] %><br>
        <%= f.select :month, ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"] %><br>

    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Hotel info up to 1000 words..." %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :meta_tags, placeholder: "Enter meta tags for image, as a comma separated list..." %><br>
<legend>Winner</legend>
        <%= f.check_box :winner %>
        <br/>

    </div>
<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "create", class: "btn-large btn-success" %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Editing hotel</h1>

<%= render "form" %>
<%= link_to 'hotels index', hotels_path %>
</div>
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<h1>New hotel</h1>

<%= render "form" %>
<%= link_to 'hotels index', hotels_path %>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any js.erb in Views/hotels?  also is @hotel nil?

Comment: nope, theres no javascript in views/hotels, and I don't think @hotel is nil? it renders all of the appropriate html on the page, so in the source I can see the form tags and placeholders and labels exist. Is it a CSS issue do you think?

Comment: It could be anything.  You must know what is in your CSS.  Did you search for 'display: none;' in your CSS files and checked the matches?  element.style is usually set directly on the HTML tag.  Search the view also place debugging string to make sure it is pulling the appropriate .html.

Comment: it seems to be bootstrap being pesky, when adding and subtracting import bootstrap lines, it comes and goes. If you stick an answer up ill upvote and accept, cheers D3mon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be anything. You must know what is in your CSS. Did you search for 'display: none;' in your CSS files and checked the matches? element.style is usually set directly on the HTML tag. Search the view also place debugging string to make sure it is pulling the appropriate .html.